# My UI is blinking and whenever i try to resize the imageview dynamically, the image disappear

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
        public void addAttendance(ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers) {
            //tl.removeView(tr);
            tl.removeAllViews();
            //addHeaderAttendance();
            ctr=0;
            for (Iterator i = attendanceusers.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

                Properties p = (Properties) i.next();

                property_list.add(p);
                /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
                tr = new TableRow(this);
    picurl=p.getPic();
                profile = new ImageView(this);

                profile.setPadding(20,50,20,50);

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {                  
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        try {
                            InputStream in = new URL(picurl).openStream();
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                           // log error
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        if (bmp != null)
                            profile.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    }

               }.execute();




                profile.setOnClickListener(this);

                //myButton.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                Ll = new LinearLayout(this);

                params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

                Ll.setPadding(0, 0, 20, 0);
                Ll.addView(profile,params);
                tr.addView((View)Ll);
    ctr++;

                 // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
        }
```

The code above is the dynamic design. There is an image there wherein i put images on my android screen that i get from my database using web service. The problem is the images are blinking and also it is too big. I think it is blinking because i am creating a thread within a thread but im still confused on how to fix it. My async task there is how i get the image.

```
public ArrayList<Properties> attendanceUse(String result) {
            ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers = new ArrayList<Properties>();
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Properties user = new Properties();

                    user.setPic(json_data.getString("student_ImgUrl"));
                    attendanceusers.add(user);
                    //attendanceusers.get(index)
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
            }
            return attendanceusers;
        }
```

The code above is how i get my image in connection with a query on php inside my htdocs. The student_imgurl is the column i select from my mysql database to get the url.

```
private void update()
        {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            String splithis;
         splithis=mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
         splited = splithis.split(" ");
        course = splited[0];
        room = splited[1];
        sections = splited[2];

            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {       
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    data = bw.getAttendanceFromDB(term, course,sections,day,room);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {       
                            try {
                    //asyntask class ito
                                ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers = attendanceUse(data);
                                addAttendance(attendanceusers); 

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // error, do something
                            }
                        }//run
                    });//handler mo
                }//runmo
            };//timer
            timer.schedule(task, 0,1000); //timer

        }
```

This is my update void. It is on a timer so that the images will update in real time.

mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            data ="";


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                               update();                 
                        }
                    });   
                }
            }).start();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return;
        }
    });
```

The code above is my code inside my Oncreate. i have a spinner/dropdown wherein they will choose course-room-section and then whenver they picked an item, the images of the students in that course-room-section will be displayed.
What i want is to stop the blinking of my UI and to resize the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts are that this could be better done by replacing your `void update()` method with an `AsyncTask<Void, Properties, Void>`  class to pull in the attendee data from the database and also download the profile image at the same time in its `doInBackground()` method.  As each attendee is loaded you can update your UI via the `publishProgress(Properties)` and `onProgressUpdate(Properties[])` methods.  This should result in a less janky UI update.

Bear in mind that if you have multiple AsyncTasks running at the same time you should execute them on the `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` to allow them to run in parallel (the default executor is `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR`)

As to the image size problems, it may be you don't appear set the correct `ImageView.ScaleType` on your view to get it to fit properly.  I expect it should be `ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE`.